# Genymotion doesn't shows virtual device that was added when I start it

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, emulation, genymotion

Recently I installed oracle virtual-box on my ubuntu 14.10 as I wanted to run a android emulator Genymotion on it.I installed Genymotion and added a MOTO-X 4.4.4 virtual device to it intially.

Everything is fine with installation. But the problem is. In order to use MOTO-X I first have to run it inside virtual box. Ther is no problem with it.

[image]

The next step is I type following command inside terminal to open genymotion
**./genymotion** inside folder wher it is installed.When it opens it doesn't shows me the virtual device i.e, MOTO-X that I added to it previously during installation instead prompts with an option to add a virtual device

[image]

I have already added a virtual device but it doesn't shows in genymotion.

Comment: In screen short it is showing "User not authenticated". Create your account online on Genymotion website and sign in using that. After that you will be able to add and run virtual devices using Genymotion application.

Comment: Free for personal use, check web site for more and latest information